# Plot regression residuals for mutliple independent variables via matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

I was wondering how do I plot my residuals for multiple independent variables? My dataset has 49 features and it has 2251 rows. My target variable is a number from 0 through 1 so I'm using a regression. I used a feature selection method to select top 10 most important features, so instead of working with 48 independent variables, I want to focus on 10. The problem: I do not know how to plot to show the residuals for 10 independent variables

my feature selection alogrithm was able to select the following 10 features:

```
'Dec','Fog-Rain','Max_Sea_Level_PressureIn','Mean_Sea_Level_PressureIn','Min_Sea_Level_PressureIn','NormalizedCC','Outlier_CC_D','Rain','Snow_flg','Rain-Thunderstorm'
```

I would like to plot the residuals for these 10 features.I would like to either make 10 different plots/figures or in order to plot the 10 independent variables in one chart I would like to make each one a different color plot. So instead of `X2_test`(which won't work since it is 10 by 2251 instead of 1 by 2251) I would like

```
X2_test['One of the 10 most important columns']
```

for example, when I try to do this:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
from pandas import read_csv
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn import preprocessing
from matplotlib import pyplot
import statsmodels.api as sm
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import explained_variance_score
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.metrics import median_absolute_error
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

df = pd.read_csv('Frequency_Data.csv')
'''
New model
'''
model2 = linear_model.LinearRegression()
train= df[:735]
test = df[735:]
X2_train=np.array(train[['Dec','Fog-Rain','Max_Sea_Level_PressureIn','Mean_Sea_Level_PressureIn','Min_Sea_Level_PressureIn','NormalizedCC','Outlier_CC_D','Rain','Snow_flg','Rain-Thunderstorm']])
X2_test=np.array(test[['Dec','Fog-Rain','Max_Sea_Level_PressureIn','Mean_Sea_Level_PressureIn','Min_Sea_Level_PressureIn','NormalizedCC','Outlier_CC_D','Rain','Snow_flg','Rain-Thunderstorm']])
y2_train = np.array(train['freq'])
y2_test = np.array(test['freq'])
model2.fit(X2_train, y2_train)
y2_pred = model2.predict(X2_test)

print('\n Accuracy')
print('-------------------------------------------------------------------')     
print 'Regression Accuracy: '+str(model2.score(X2_test,y2_test))

print('\n Model Evaluation:')
print('-------------------------------------------------------------------')
print'Explained Variance: ' + str(explained_variance_score(y2_test, y2_pred))
print'Mean Absloute sq Error: '+str(mean_absolute_error(y2_test, y2_pred))
print'Mean sq Error: '+str(mean_squared_error(y2_test, y2_pred))
print'Median Absolute Error: '+str(median_absolute_error(y2_test, y2_pred))
#print'R2: '+str(r2_score(y2_test, y2_pred))
error = y_test - y2_pred
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Plot outputs
plt.scatter(X2_test['Dec'], y2_test,  color='black')
plt.plot(X2_test['Dec'], model2.predict(X2_test['Dec']), color='blue',
     linewidth=3)
plt.xticks(())
plt.yticks(())
plt.show()
```

are the 10 important features, when I try to even plot one of them, `Dec`, it gave me the following error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (563,) (1516,)
```

how can I plot the 10 different features as a different color and then have a legend that let's the user know which color corresponds to which feature.Or how could I produce 10 different plots/figures showing the residuals? Or is there another way to evaluate my errors for each of the 10 variables? My dataset is in daily frequency so I would like to zoom in to see which time period created the largest error

Comment: I think this is pretty easy to answer once you tell us exactly what `X_test` and `y_test` are and what they contain. It's always a good idea to split the problem up and ask the broadest question possible, such that people do not need to be experts in one library (or even don't have to have it ever used) in order to solve the problem unrelated to that library.  Alternatively you can of course use the sklearn tag and wait for someone from that field to come along and give you an answer.

Comment: I partitioned my dataset into a train and test set. `X2_test` are the 10 independent variables found in the test set while `y2_test` is my target or dependent variable found in my test set

Comment: you could look into seaborn, especially factorplot or the turoial "plotting on data aware grids"